# My xdiagnose does not work?

Tags: 12.04, inspiron

When I click on the application, the application does not run or is not visible.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal. then, type:

```
gksudo xdiagnose
```

Comment: D'oh! Sorry new to this platform, should have thought of that :-S Thank you for you help, it now works fine! :-)

Comment: @Georgelemental: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/410541/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your own edits in the future.