# What is xdiagnose?

Tags: xorg

I was just browsing around when I came by [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/389803/163331). It suggests removing xdiagnose if your laptop is overheating. I immediately fired up the dash and clicked on the xdiagnose icon, nothing happened. I searched around and saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410465/my-xdiagnose-does-not-work). The answer was to run it as root user. I did that only to face this error:

```
subroot@subroot:~$ sudo xdiagnose
[sudo] password for subroot: 
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key
** (xdiagnose:5280): WARNING **: Command line `dbus-launch --autolaunch=7f8731869e1c690b8205727e0000000a --binary-syntax --close-stderr' exited with non-zero exit status 1: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyInvalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyAutolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.\n
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/xdiagnose", line 37, in <module>
    from xdiagnose.applet import XDiagnoseApplet
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdiagnose/applet.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 76, in load_module
    dynamic_module._load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 224, in _load
    overrides_modules = __import__('gi.overrides', fromlist=[self._namespace])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gtk.py", line 1533, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Gtk couldn't be initialized")
RuntimeError: Gtk couldn't be initialized
subroot@subroot:~$
```

`gksu xdiagnose` doesn't help either, it displays no errors but it doesn't do anything either.

Then I tried removing it `apt-get remove`, only to be told that the `ubuntu-desktop` package will be removed also. Of course I didn't.

This brings me to my question, what is xdiagnose and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `xdiagnose` - Analysis tools for troubleshooting X.org problems. See its help:

  ```
  sudo  xdiagnose -h
  ```
- Try reinstalling, by purging without removing dependents:

  ```
  sudo dpkg --purge --force-all xdiagnose
  sudo apt-get install xdiagnose
  ```
- Edit `/etc/sudoers` (as `root`), add this line:

  ```
  Defaults env_keep="XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY TZ PS2 PS1 PATH LS_COLORS KRB5CCNAME HOSTNAME HOME DISPLAY COLORS"`
  ```

  Ref: [Can't open Gedit as root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414785/cant-open-gedit-as-root/414810#414810)

[image]

Comment: Still getting same error.

Comment: Try `export DISPLAY=:0.0 ; sudo xdiagnose`, if no success see with `rm ~/.Xauthority*` then save your work on other windows and restart lightdm `sudo restart lightdm`, try again `sudo xdiagnose`.

Comment: Did some answer and found an answer. http://askubuntu.com/a/414810/163331

Comment: @AvatarParto, Such similar bugs will have different titles and error messages, It's new to me. Now, I should be able to figure out as `sudo` problem. I have updated answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @AvatarParto, It's weird, that my `etc/sudoers` has no `env_keep` line but every thing works well. I think there is other place (config file) that cover similar option.

Comment: How about if you run `sudo sudo -V`? For me, I think it's something I did with either `dconf editor` or `Gconf`...not sure though.